# Drupal CMS : monolithic vs multisite strategy

Tags: drupal, architecture, content-management-system, multisite

what are the pros and cons of these two strategies?

For a big website with thousands of pages, tenths of additional modules, thousands of editors with different permissions, Can the monolithic approach be considered at all ?

would it be usable and maintainable, sufficientely flexible ?

Are there some usercase to read from for both strategies ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to have multiple sites with different architectures, different databases, and different users, then use multi-sites.

Drupal has been built to handle thousands of pages (nodes), with equally as many users. The different permissions can be a little tedious, but yes, you can do it. You can get even more specific with permissions with the [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module.

As for sustainability, this depends on how you build it. If you were to build the site to [Drupal Best Practices](https://www.drupal.org/best-practices), any Drupal developer will be able to pick it up and run with it. If you do anything custom, make sure it is thoroughly documented and implemented correctly so to minimize the room for error.

You can view case studies in Drupal [on Drupal.org's Case studies page](https://www.drupal.org/case-studies). These include rather large sites such as [weather.com](https://www.drupal.org/node/2374175), and [Georgetown University in Qatar](https://www.drupal.org/node/2635572). I can't find any specific case studies on multisite (probably because that would be a little difficult to document multiple websites without giving away some layer of privacy on the developer's part) but there is this [white-paper from Acquia entitled "Drupal Multi-Site"](https://www.acquia.com/resources/whitepapers/drupal-multi-site) that I would recommend.

Without more details of the project, it's kind of hard to make a recommendation on what you are trying to accomplish.